# NextJS app does not work on IE and Safari throwing an unexpected error has occurred

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application, vercel

I have an app built with next js , unfortunately the app works on other browsers except safari and internet explorer, the app throws error "unexpected error occurred"

i tried debugging with the dev console...and it jus keep console logging the same error, i was able to take a screen shoot, here are images

[image]

[image: this the screen shot from internet explorer and its the same for safari when on local host]

Comment: Have you tried this solution suggested in this GitHub issue: [IE11, development, HMR: Object doesn't support property or method 'attachShadow'.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13231#issuecomment-711484680)?